# how to add a line in between 2 block

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts, customer-login

HI I am trying to change the look of the customer login page.
How do add a line or separator in between this 2 blocks?
like the image I found on net. When in mobile view the line will gone.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to following way

Ex: like below is your second Block

```
<div class="col-2 registered-users" </div>
```

**Below css**

```
<style>
.col-2 {
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ededed;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 770px){
.block.block-customer-login {
    border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}
}
```

https://drops.meetanshi.com/CB74kq